# Flutter project won't start

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to run any flutter project, the following errors are displayed:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

flutter doctor -v:

```
        [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570], locale ru-RU)
        • Flutter version 3.13.8 on channel stable at C:\flutter
        • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
        • Framework revision 6c4930c4ac (2 days ago), 2023-10-18 10:57:55 -0500
        • Engine revision 767d8c75e8
        • Dart version 3.1.4
        • DevTools version 2.25.0

    [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
        • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
        • Platform android-34-ext8, build-tools 34.0.0
        • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
        • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
        • All Android licenses accepted.

    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
        • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

    [√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.5)
        • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
        • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.7.34202.233
        • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

    [√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
        • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
        • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
          https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
        • Dart plugin can be installed from:
          https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
        • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

    [√] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
        • VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
        • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

    [√] Connected device (2 available)
        • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570]
        • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.89

    [√] Network resources
        • All expected network resources are available.
```

Ignore this: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Add flutter doctor result to question, also, did you tried  flutter clean ? 
and another question, is the project new, or old project?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, opdated. It doesn't matter if the project is new or old, everyone gets this error. flutter clean doesn't help